# How can I replace part of the content of <div> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, string

I need to partially replace contend of div every time when I have new data.

```
<div id="name">Your name is </div>

$('#name').append(newName);
```

How can I replace the name with new data using `jQuery`?

Example

```
Your name is John Doe
```

and after applying changes (newName is 'Bob Murphy'):

```
Your name is Bob Murphy
```

Comment: Insert an empty span and change the text of that span. Why overcomplicating things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to create a `span` for name.

HTML:

```
<div>Your name is <span id="name">John Doe</span></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#name').text('Bob Murphy');
```

Comment: You lose the efficiency of the `id` by doing `$('span#name')` (I know, I know, it's not the point of your answer).

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I don't think the performance loss is significant here and I would also suggest to cache the element if it's going to be accessed multiple times. Anyway, thanks for pointing this out. Updated the answer.

Comment: Signifiant, yes it is. By a lot. Does it matter here? Probably not, but I still think it is for the best to learn the best practice! Still, this is the answer I'd use :)

Comment: Just to let others know about the performance impact @Karl-AndréGagnon is talking about: its like ~38k vs ~42k ops/sec on [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/tag-id-vs-id-jquery-selector). Pretty significant for hard real-time jQuery apps. Jk. :) `$('#name')` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can place your dynamic content in a separate nested tag and manipulate that. So your HTML would be

```
<div id="name">Your name is <span class="spanInnerName"></span></div>
```

And Manipulate it as

```
var newName = "New Name";
$('#name .spanInnerName').html(newName);
```

This would prove to be faster and more manipulative.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#name').text(function(txt){
   return txt.replace(oldName, newName);
});
```

would do.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the below code

```
$('#text').text(function(x){
   return $(this).text().toString().replace(oldName, newName);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all of the above about adding a span and replacing the text but you don't need jQuery to do it.  If it is already included in your project then go ahead and use it.  If not, you could do the same thing like this:

```
<div>Your name is <span id="name"></span></div>

var name = 'New Name';
document.getElementById('#name').textContent = name;

//if you wanted to pass HTML in: 
//document.getElementById('#name').innerHTML = name;
```